# Pending Questions

Tags: tangle, pending

I moved some IOTA in from Binance; I see the IOTA but it still says pending. Before I move that to a new seed, it should say confirmed, correct?

Also, Anytime I want to send IOTA to my seed, I have to generate a new address by attaching to the Tangle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move IOTA's that are not confirmed to one of your addresses - so you have to wait for confirmation before sending it on.

It's recommended to create a new address for each incoming transfer because -
If you get two to same address, the first may conrift fast, and second can be pending for a while . If you then spend the first arrivals before second is confirmed, you will receive to an address already 'used' when second trnasfer is confirmed. This will lead to a key-reuse when you try to spend the second arrivals.

Comment: Thanks. I was confirmed on the side I sent from, but the receiving side says pending. I should wait til that confirms. Anything I can do to speed that up; been a couple hours or more.

Answer (score 1):

I had to continue to reattach the transaction using different nodes in order for it to finally confirm.